# Select all flagged values in enum using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, enums, enum-flags

I have a collection of flagged enums, like this:

```
[Flags]
enum EnumThing
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4,
    D = 8
}
```

I'd like to select all flags in the collection using LINQ. Let's say that the collection is this:

```
EnumThing ab = EnumThing.A | EnumThing.B;
EnumThing ad = EnumTHing.A | EnumThing.D;    
var enumList = new List<EnumThing> { ab, ad };
```

In bits it will look like this:

```
0011
1001
```

And the desired outcome like this:

```
1011
```

The desired outcome could be achieved in plain C# by this code:

```
EnumThing wishedOutcome = ab | ad;
```

or in SQL by

```
select 3 | 9
```

But how do I select all selected flags in `enumList` using Linq into a new `EnumThing`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to parse a flagged enum to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668496/most-efficient-way-to-parse-a-flagged-enum-to-a-list)

Comment: I suppose you meant `EnumThing ab = EnumThing.A *|* EnumThing.B;`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple linq solution would be this:

```
EnumThing ab = EnumThing.A | EnumThing.B;
EnumThing ad = EnumThing.A | EnumThing.D;
var enumList = new List<EnumThing> { ab, ad };

var combined = enumList.Aggregate((result, flag) => result | flag);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ `Aggregate` function:

```
var desiredOutcome = enumList.Aggregate((x, y) => x | y);
```

Note that if list is empty - that will throw an exception, so check if list is empty before doing that.

```
var desiredOutcome = enumList.Count > 0 ? 
    enumList.Aggregate((x, y) => x | y) : 
    EnumThing.Default; // some default value, if possible
```